# Combine 2 if statements with vloookups

Tags: excel, formula

I have searched everywhere but i can not find the answer i am looking for. I need to combine two formulas that both have if and vlookup statements in them. I can find answers on how to combine with if and vlookups singularly but not together. Does anyone know how i would combine these two formulas:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C7,'Drop Down Fields'!E4:I32,1,0)="Other",'ECO Form'!L30,"")
=IF(ISBLANK(C7),"",VLOOKUP(C7,'Drop Down Fields'!E4:I32,2))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand  what sort of output you expect with a given input

Comment: So if the cell is not blank, look up a range and find the array, if the cell is not blank and also says "other", it looks up a different range. It is about finding vendor numbers against a vendor. If it's other, it's in a different group of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, let me know how you go:

```
=IF(C7="Other",'ECO Form'!L30,VLOOKUP(C7,'Drop Down Fields'!E4:I32,2))
```

I am not sure if you also care if "Other" must exist as an entry in the cell range E4:E32 on the 'Drop Down Fields' worksheet? If so, then you will need to use your original IF condition as it is from the first formula as below and the vlookup of 2nd formula simply gets plugged into the *'else'* part of the first IF formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C7,'Drop Down Fields'!E4:I32,1,0)="Other",'ECO Form'!L30,VLOOKUP(C7,'Drop Down Fields'!E4:I32,2))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.